# Comment comprendre "déplacement majeur entre des conceptions" ?

Tags: expressions

Une des activités que je voudrais faire est décrite ci-dessous:

**En vous appuyant sur les analyses des définitions du bilinguisme, dites quel est le déplacement majeur entre une conception commune du bilinguisme et une conception fonctionnelle, débouchant sur la notion de compétence plurilingue ?**

Mon problème est que je ne peux pas cerner la signification de l'expression *quel est le déplacement majeur entre...* - mon intuition me dit que je pourrais la traduire au mot *différence*, c-à-d *quel est la différence entre...*

Comment: Quel jargon ! S'il faut absolument comprendre cet énoncé, je pense en effet _déplacement_ signifie à peu près _différence_ (en conséquence d'une évolution, peut-être). Bon courage !

Comment: Cela est non pas  du jargon mais du vocabulaire spécialisé ; il reste à savoir si l'assemblage présent qui en est fait représente une réalité ou non.

Answer (score -1):

Lorsqu'il est question d'un déplacement dans un contexte abstrait de concepts purs on doit tout simplement penser en termes d'évolution d'un concept qui a aboutit à un concept plus ou moins voisin ou tout simplement de *coexistence de concepts* qui ne découlent pas l'un de l'autre par une évolution tangible mais qui néanmoins sont voisins et concerne tous deux le sujet discuté, ce qui n'empêche pas la comparaison et donc la reconnaissance d'un lien que l'on appelle encore le déplacement. Dans cette phrase on ne veut considérer que la partie importante de cette évolution, d'où l'adjectif « majeur ».

Le glissement est un type de déplacement ; on dit plutôt « glissement » parce que c'est un déplacement dont les principes sont plus ou moins intangibles. Cependant on peut quand même utiliser « déplacement » à la place de « glissement ». « Glissement » est très utilisé en linguistique.